# A note manager with flexible tagging and hierarchies for organizing user feedback

Tags: web-apps, note-taking

## Requirements

- One step changing the name of a tag on all tagged entries.
- Tag hierarchies, being able to tag a tag
- Linking to tags and notes with integrated search: ability
  to quickly look up the target of my link, search as I type would be appreciated here
- "What links here" autosummary

## Motivation

I have a support form where customers enter their issues and feature requests. That means when I collect the submissions I am presented with a large number of filled forms that I need to process and organize.

I assume that my workflow and requirements are essentially identical to anybody using such system:

I go through the forms, identify issues that people have, group similar issues together, Create tickets (notes).

Sometimes one submission relates to two or more requests. A concrete recommendation how to better solve some use case is both a feature request and a complaint that the old way is bad. Now I need to reference one piece of feedback from two different issues.

Sometimes I realize that I need to redo my classification, so I need to retag some notes.

I am not looking for bug tracking software, because I primarily need the note organizing functionality I described. Being able to set issues as resolved could come useful, but it very low on my requirement list.

## Self-hosted web app

Ideally I am looking for a free and self-hosted web app.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? If not, then maybe a personal wiki could solve it for you. See [my answer](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23425/14982) here for a little more details.